# How to replace a variable's value using common shell commands?

Tags: bash, replace

I have a text file with lines like this:

```
  variable_name : value
```

I need to make a bash script to replace "value" with a fixed value I know (let say "myvalue").

I don't know previously which is the variable_name's value.

I need to use bash commands that can be used in any default installation of linux box like sed, grep, awk, etc.

I know how to do it with sed when I know the "value" string, but I can't figure out how to do it by searching in the file by the name of the variable.

**EDIT**: I add some complexity to this task, I have to exclude some patterns with a fixed text, for example if I have:

```
  variable_name : value
  variable_name : VARIABLE_NAME > lorem_ipsum
```

I have to exclude the replacement with the string VARIABLE_NAME. The result must be:

```
  variable_name : myvalue
  variable_name : VARIABLE_NAME > lorem_ipsum
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: for your newly edited requirement, case insensitive? in all case? e.g. VaRiabLe_NaMe too? ane what happened if a var looks like:  `username : username` ?

Comment: Is the value allowed to have spaces?

Comment: @Kent : the left side is always lower case and the right side is always UPPER CASE

Comment: @Neuquino lorem_ipsum won't get replaced??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you looking for this?

```
echo "variable_name : value"|sed -r 's/(variable_name :)(.*)/\1myvalue/'
variable_name :myvalue
```

**EDIT** for new requirement

you said you will exclude replacement with string VARIABLE_NAME, so I assume that  `(space)> lorem_ipsum` will be replaced by new value.

so this line may help:

```
awk 'BEGIN{v="variable_name";V=toupper(v); FS=OFS=" : "} $1~"^"v{$2=($2~"^"V)?V"myValue":"myValue"}1' file
```

take a look this:

```
kent$  echo "variable_name : value
variable_name : VARIABLE_NAME > lorem_ipsum"|awk 'BEGIN{v="variable_name";V=toupper(v); FS=OFS=" : "} $1~"^"v{$2=($2~"^"V)?V"myValue":"myValue"}1';                         
variable_name : myValue
variable_name : VARIABLE_NAMEmyValue
```

**EDIT2**

Neuquino, you should explain your requirement more clear..... anyway:

```
 kent$  echo "variable_name : value
variable_name : VARIABLE_NAME > lorem_ipsum"|awk 'BEGIN{v="variable_name";V=toupper(v); FS=OFS=" : "} $1~"^"v && $2!~"^"V{$2="myValue"}1';                                  
variable_name : myValue
variable_name : VARIABLE_NAME > lorem_ipsum
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, check the recent EDIT. Thanks

Comment: the line with VARIABLE_NAME should not be touched, but with this solution we are almost there!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F":" 'BEGIN{OFS=":"}/variable_name/{$2="my value"}1' your_file
```

also you can use perl:

```
perl -pe 'if(/variable_name/){$_=~s/(variable_name :).*/$1 myvalue/g;}' your_file
```

if you want to do inplace replacement:

```
perl -pi -e 'if(/variable_name/){$_=~s/(variable_name :).*/$1 myvalue/g;}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

awk method:

```
echo "  variable_name : value" | awk -F: -v OFS=: '/variable_name/{ $2=" value2"}1'
```